# Why simplex algorithm works for solving Linear Programming

Tags: algorithm

We know that simplex is a very famous algorithm used to solve linear programming probleams, and I know how to use it, but what confused me is that why simplex always assumes that one of the vertices of the Polyhedron is the optimal solution ?

Comment: Google for Fundamental Theorem of Linear Programming

Comment: @gd1 thx for your answer, but I find it a little hard to understand, can anyone give any easy-to-understand explanation ?

Comment: @BitHigher The theory behind linear programming is comparatively advanced. There is no very intuitive way to understand it without doing a certain amount of math.

Comment: @BitHigher : I'm sorry it seemed like a RTFM-like answer. Actually, I don't exactly remember the reason why the optimal solution is on the vertices, but I know that the answer is in the Fundamental Theorem and it's not so hard if you know the formal concepts of convex region, polyhedron, segment and vertex. Feel free to read all the answers here but remember that they can give you an intuitive glimpse about the answer you are looking for, but the definitive, formal, rock-solid answer is in that theorem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can refer to the geometry, especially the analytic geometry. Simplex algorithm actually means that the optimal result always stay in the vertex instead of in the line or in the face, it's very intuitive.

Comment: yes, I know the geometry meaning of simplex algorithm, but I just can not understand it, or to say in another way, I don't how to prove it

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, walking inside the polyhedron in the direction of increasing profit you'll end up in a vertex. A lot like this observation: if you lay a box on one of its corners and let a marble roll from the top, it'll end up in this corner.

There's one case to take into account when you stop your walk on a side perpendicular to the increasing profit line, then all the points of this side are optimal solutions. Therefore you can select any vertices of this side.

Answer (score 1):

Given a linear objective function *f* and a polyhedron *P*, you can reason as follows.

1. Any point *p* in the interior of *P* cannot be a strict local maximum.  Take a line *L* through *p*, and restrict *f* to *L*.  Parameterize *L* as *p + t(q - p)* for some point *q*, and *t* real.  Then the restriction of *f* is linear in *t*, and there is an interval (a, b) containing 0 that *t* is valid in. Depending on the coefficient of *t*, go in one direction or another to increase *f*.  If the coefficient of *t* is 0, just go as far as possible in one direction.
2. Any point in the interior of a face of *P* has the same property where you restrict the lines to stay on that face.
3. Walk down the boundary simplices, dimension by dimension.  You end up at a vertex; local maxima are at vertices.
4. This does not mean you chose the correct lines to follow; the complexity of the simplex algorithm is how to go the correct directions.